# MYSQL SELECT INDEX NOT FAST

Tags: mysql, indexing

I’m facing problems with `Mysql` and `Index`. My problem is that I created an index to mysql database with 50M rows.

I’m trying to do this :

```
SELECT userid from database where userid=4 ORDER by id Desc limit 10
```

I created an index in `userid`, and when I explain the query it shows me in Rows field 92000 records, but it takes at least 15-40s to display results in first selection. If I try again a second later of first select it runs very fast, 0.02s.

I realized that if I change Select without use index my explain goes to 3000 in Rows field, but have the same time problem.

Other information that can be important is that my table is myIsam.

What’s the problem with my index and my query?

Comment: Can you post the `EXPLAIN` plan too. It should be able to fetch this without scanning 90k rows and sorting.

Comment: here is a picture of my explain https://imgur.com/a/4EnW2EP

Comment: Is this InnoDB? Is `userid` INT or BIGINT?.. uh .. maybe post the table schema too :)

Comment: no, i changed my question. Is myIsam, and userid is begint! Id is PRIMARY key auto increment and userid is bigint

Comment: In that case you can change the index from `(userid)` to `(userid,id)`. This will allow it to get the top 10 without scanning a lot.

Comment: but i have same problem with userid that has less data than this, for example, if i select userid=2 there is only 520 rows, but this still too slow. All queries are very slow in the first selection, after os very fast, and some time later backs to long time

Comment: For that you either need more RAM, a less loaded server, or faster IO on the server. Also be careful, because changing the index from one to two columns will make it twice as big, and can make RAM/IO problem worse.

Comment: I have 8gb of ram, i don’t really know if I use more will change something because with this query my memory usage still in 55%

Comment: Memory usage has to be configured. I'm unfamiliar with MyISAM settings however, so I can't help with that.

Comment: I know that, but this is what I’m trying to say, because the problem is not memory, is something with the SELECT, but i’ll try your suggestion adding Index with 2 cols. How can I change my created index? What query should I execute?

Comment: That query will display "4" 10 (or fewer) times.  If this is a simplification of the real query, then it lost too much meat.

Comment: Do switch to InnoDB.  Do provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.